# Is it possible to format a date with sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite, date

At start you have a string 'DDMMYYYY HHMMSS' and I want at the end to insert the string in a date field  in sqlite3 database. The program is made in python. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Even though the ".schema" indicates that the field is a date or timestamp field... the field is actually a string.  You can format the string anyway you want. If memory serves... their is no validation at all.

Answer (score 1):

I believe sqlite3 doesn't have a DATE type, therefore you have to do it manually in your python code. Either you store the date in exactly this form or you convert it into a timestamp or some other form.

Have a look at the [datetime module](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) and especially at the `strptime` function.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by the other answers, it is stored as a string.  However, it **will** be recognized as a date if you insert it in one of the following formats

Time Strings

A time string can be in any of the following formats:

```
 1. YYYY-MM-DD
 2. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
 3. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
 4. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
 5. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
 6. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
 7. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
 8. HH:MM
 9. HH:MM:SS
10. HH:MM:SS.SSS
11. now
12. DDDDDDDDDD
```

**REFERENCE:**

---

[Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)